# Why does Facebook share dialog not show up?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am currently trying to enable the functionality to share a video through Facebook, however the share dialog does not show up.

Here's the code:

```
        let video = ShareVideo(videoURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Rap God", withExtension: "mp4")!)
        let content = ShareVideoContent()
        content.video = video
        content.contentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Rap God", withExtension: "mp4")!
        let dialog = ShareDialog(fromViewController: self, content: content, delegate: self)
        dialog.shareContent = content
        dialog.shouldFailOnDataError = true
        dialog.mode = .shareSheet
        dialog.fromViewController = self
        dialog.show()
        print(dialog.canShow)
```

print(dialog.canShow) is here equal to "false". Could please tell me how I could fix this?

Comment: Why aren’t you using UIActivityController?

Comment: @PGDev little question not linked to this, would you know how to enable all activity types in UIActivityViewController? Like Instagram, Snapchat, Gmail, ... make them all selectable

Comment: They are enabled by default. Any app installed that has a Share extension will appear in UIActivityViewController.

Comment: @PGDev Are you really sure? because I remember I had to do it manually

Comment: Yes they appear automatically.

Comment: @PGDev well okay thank you for your answer